# Linux Mint 18 Secure Bluetooth

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth

I have this angst that bluetooth on my Linux Mint 18 laptop isn't secure by default.

There is a "Mobile Network" nearby called "`t'cry'la`" that keeps reappearing in my network connections (bluetooth).  I have Docker and Virtualbox installed.

Bluetooth in Settings doesn't offer options to turn this off. It says my laptop is "visible and available for file transfers."

Is it a security issue?

How do I turn off discoverability, connections, transfers, and pairing, so those things only happen when I take action to turn them on.

Thanks!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450698/how-to-turn-on-and-off-bluetooth-visibility-mode